# Is there an alternate way to set directory wide config in dbt? (not dbt_project.yml)

Tags: dbt

I have been using a config macro in each model of my project, and many of them have the same exact config.

I know you can set general settings on a folder in dbt_project.yml, but we have many developers and many directories and having the configuration there gets messy very fast.

I'm wondering if there’s an alternate way to set such a config on a directory level? Like with a config.yml in the directory itself?